# Can't execute function in a while loop

Tags: python, function, input, while-loop

I have the following code inside a while loop:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("y or n")
    if user_input == "y":
        yes()
        break
    if user_input == "n":
        no()
        break

def yes():
    print("yes")

def no():
    print("no")
```

When I input "y", this message occurs that prevents the function from being executed.

```
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

Why is this? And How can i solve it?

Comment: Define yes() before the while loop

Comment: Apologies, but what reason is provided to reduce the score of my post to -1? @TimCastelijns do you know by chance/

Comment: Probably because this is basic and had been asked before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python executes code from top to bottom, creating function objects as it comes across `def` statements. When it starts executing your `while` loop, it hasn't reached your `def yes():` line yet, so the function *doesn't exist yet*.

Move the functions to the top, before your `while` loop.

Alternatively, move the loop into another function, and call that new function *after* the `yes` and `no` functions have been defined.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the functions `yes()` and `no()` before while.

Like this:

```
def yes():
    print("yes")

def no():
    print("no")

while True:
    user_input = input("y or n")
    if user_input == "y":
        yes()
        break
    if user_input == "n":
        no()
        break
```

This will work fine.